# Take screenshot when app closed

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I want to take screenshots of any running app, while my app is in the background.

I set a timer in applicationDidEnterBackground method.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.takeSS), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And I created a method called takeSS

```
func takeSS(){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((window?.bounds.size)!, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    self.window?.drawHierarchy(in: (window?.bounds)!, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

It takes screen shoot every 10 seconds and save it to the camera roll. But screenshots are white and blank photos. Is there any way to take screen shoot when app is closed.

Thank you.

Comment: There's only a few types of background processing allowed -- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4 -- and this isn't one of them.  You're essentially asking for how a sandboxed app can spy on other sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Apple blocked the API you need to take a screenshot of anything but your App's content in iOS 9, for security reasons. I researched this extensively for a company I worked for, and found that it is impossible unless the device is jailbroken.